# How does sound travel in the form of transverse wave in solids and on the surface of liquids?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I am not able to comprehend. Can someone explain by visualizing that how it happens ?

Comment: Did you look up phonons?

Comment: Each atom pushes the next, then goes back and gets pushed again, and so on.

Comment: It's not clear what the implied distinction from games or inside liquid is.